# Single kafka producer for 4 topics

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I use spring-boot with transactional kafka. I have 4 topics where i need to send kafka messages. How could I design my application for creating single producer for all topics?
Any example?

Now I can't understand how kafkaProducerFactory create producers. Sometime it creates single, sometime it create 2 producers, sometime more.

app.yaml config :

```
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:29092
      transaction-id-prefix: tx-
      properties:
        enable.idempotence: true
        acks: all
        retries: 3
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection: 5
        max.block.ms: 10000
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

Send class :

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaRespService {
  private final KafkaTemplate<String, KafkaMessageDto> kafkaTemplate;

  public void sendMessage(String topic, KafkaMessageDto kafkaMessageDto) {
    MetadataDto metadataDto = kafkaMessageDto.getMetadata();
    String key = String.valueOf(metadataDto.getId());
    kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, kafkaMessageDto);
  }
}
```

Kafka CLuster
[image]

Comment: Can you explain the reason why you want to enforce a single producer?

Comment: i want to make some tests to see performance of both ways

Comment: I have not been able to find a way to enforce this, may be someone else will respond if they find something. I think I understand the logic though. For Non transactional producer - a single instance can suffice and be returned even across multiple threads since it is thread safe. However this is not the case for transactional producers, so it makes sense to have a pool of them.